# Check Property Valid Value

Tags: python-3.x, properties, kivy

Good day. I know that kivy already has an OptionProperty that limits the variable assignable to it. Kivy has some built-in variables that accept a certain set of values. In my case, I need to assign a transition keyword to `screenmanager.transition.direction` according to `screenmanager.transition`. Is there a list I could pull from to check my keyword against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the legal options for `direction` as:

```
SlideTransition.direction.options
```